# Mounting a windows network folder

Tags: networking, mount

I am trying to mount a Windows network folder.  I have the Windows folder set to share with everyone for the read only format.  I believe this lets anyone on the local network access the file.

Next, in terminal:

```
silver@TheSilverLaptop:~$ mkdir ~/desktop/Windows-Share sudo mount.cifs //windows-computer-name/folder-name
```

terminal responds with:

```
mkdir:cannot create directory '/home/silver/desktop/Windows-Share' No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why it says this.  Of course there is no directory, that's why I am asking to create it.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'sudo': File exists

mkdir: cannot create directory 'mount.cifs': File exists

mkdir: cannot create directory '//windows-computer-name/folder-name' no such file or directory.
```

Note: for windows-computer-name/folder-name
I have plugged in the name of my Windows computer and the folder on my windows computer..

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization matters when it comes to Linux based OSes.  The folder for the desktop is `~/Desktop` so your command should be:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/Windows-Share
```

Then to mount, it is source of mount then to destination of mount as a separate command.

```
sudo mount.cifs //windows-computer-name/folder-name ~/Desktop/Windows-Share
```

It can all be done as one type in command separated with && like so:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/Windows-Share && sudo mount.cifs //windows-computer-name/folder-name ~/Desktop/Windows-Share
```

Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently for username and password settings that should be required by Windows shares.

Comment: I think your response is spot on.  After following your instructions I am prompted for the sudo password and the root password.  However, after that, I am getting a "mount error(13): Permission denied."  Admittedly, it's possibly related to the settings on the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I just tested connecting to the computer from another Windows machine (using network file sharing).  that does work.

Comment: @whitelightning You might want to look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently and see how to user the username and password for connecting to Windows shares.